# Unknown column '$1' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm getting this error whilst trying to execute an SQL query to my MySQL database from NodeJS. This is the query I tried to execute:

```
db.query("insert into items(category,description,user_id) values($1,$2,$3);",
[req.body.category,req.body.description,req.body.user_id],function(error,results){ 

some follow-up code..
```

Comment: Which class do you use for the mysql connection?

Comment: Try `values(?, ?, ?);` instead. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$1, $2, $3` is not correct. You need to use `?` as a placeholder instead

```
insert into items(category,description,user_id) values(?,?,?);
```

The question marks will get substituted by the values you pass in the array

Comment: Yep, that was it! Weirdly enough I tried that as my first guess but it seemed to fail for an another reason totally. Thank you.